# How To Remove force " Select Language , Google Translate " Text / bottom in G Logo Area?

Tags: css, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BW0Y.jpg)

Forcely Showing " select language " Text In G translate Logo Area! It's Very Irritating......

Before : That Text not showing that Area! Always Reflecting " G LOGO " only! but now! 2 Texts ( Select Language & Google Translate ) showing forcely on that area! how to remove that?

anyone please share that text removing css code!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.